# How can I know if a VM is used or not?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, datastore

I am running ESXi 4.1.

In my main datastore I have  plenty of folders, some of them has logical names, while the others don't, they hold BASE configurations/images of clients that I duplicate and activate.

I only have a fraction of the actual clients loaded and running on the server. How can I know, but looking in the datastore folder, if the VM is in the inventory or not?

- If I right click on the vmx file, I can add it to the inventory - EVEN if the same client/folder is already active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I know, but looking in the datastore folder, if the VM is in
>   the inventory or not?

You can't.

We could do with knowing what your *actual* problem here is, for instance if you have have a seriously large number of files hanging around in a DS and you don't know if they're running then simply SvMotioning the running ones to a different DS will leave you KNOWING that the existing DS doesn't contain any running VMs. You can confirm this by viewing the DS and selecting the 'VMs' tab to check that there are no running VMs in it. If your root problem is something other than this you need to come back to us with more details.